# How to get list of employee within date of joining and resignation including null dates in laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have employees table and a join to another table where it has the date of joining and date of resignation, the default value is null
So when I select a date, let us say today, I want to retrieve all employees where the selected date falls between their date of joining and resignation date, but default value of resignation will be null for many. so the query is not working. Below is my current code

```
\DB::table('caregivers')
    ->join('caregiver_professional_details',function($q){
            $q->on('caregivers.id', '=','caregiver_professional_details.caregiver_id')
    ->where('caregiver_professional_details.role','=','Caregiver')
    ->whereDate('caregiver_professional_details.date_of_joining','<=',$date           
    ->whereDate('caregiver_professional_details.resignation_date','>=',$date);
})
```

[image]

So when i select any date less than or equal to 20 Dec 2018, both 1 and 2 should show up
if i select 21 and above, only 2 should show up

Comment: provide sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
\DB::table('caregivers')
  ->join('caregiver_professional_details',function($q){
        $q->on('caregivers.id', '=','caregiver_professional_details.caregiver_id')
  ->where('caregiver_professional_details.role','=','Caregiver')
  ->where(function($r) use ($date){
        $r->whereDate('caregiver_professional_details.date_of_joining','<=',$date)
          ->orWhereNull('caregiver_professional_details.date_of_joining');
   })
   ->where(function($r) use ($date){
        $r->whereDate('caregiver_professional_details.resignation_date','>=',$date)
          ->orWhereNull('caregiver_professional_details.resignation_date');
   });
})
```

Comment: @Shidharta Das Thanks. It works properly. Although its a modification to Tim's solution, your solution will take additional care of null values in DOJ column too.

Comment: @NitishPatra I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is that you want to match an employee where the input date is before the joining date, *and* the resignation date is later than the input date *or* the resignation date is `NULL`, in which case we can assume that he has not yet resigned.  That is, I am suggesting that you want the following `WHERE` clause:

```
date_of_joining <= DATE AND
(resignation_date >= DATE OR resignation_date IS NULL)
```

To form this logic in your Laravel code, we can use an anonymous function:

```
DB::table('caregivers')
    ->join('caregiver_professional_details', function($q) {
        $q->on('caregivers.id', '=',
            'caregiver_professional_details.caregiver_id')
    ->where('caregiver_professional_details.role','=','Caregiver')
     ->whereDate('caregiver_professional_details.date_of_joining', '<=', $date)
     ->where(function($query) {
            $query->whereDate('caregiver_professional_details.resignation_date', '>=', $date)
                  ->orWhereNull('caregiver_professional_details.resignation_date');
        })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tim Biegeleisen.Shidhartha Das's answer seems more applicable in my condition as it takes another step into consideration in case date of joining remains null, it will cater to both the conditions, in case DOJ is also null.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `where()` with closure + `orWhereNull()`.

Also, I think it is better to use alias for better readability.

```
$caregivers = \DB::table('caregivers')
    ->join('caregiver_professional_details as details', function($query){
        $query
            ->on('caregivers.id', '=', 'details.caregiver_id')
            ->where('details.role', '=', 'Caregiver')
            ->whereDate('details.date_of_joining', '<=', $date)
            ->where(function($query){
                $query
                    ->whereDate('details.resignation_date', '>=', $date)
                    ->orWhereNull('details.resignation_date');
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I congratulate you, but you have 2 syntax errors, format and readability of code smells. Nice point: you use return in where closure, but don't use it in join closure.

Comment: @IndianCoding Syntax errors are fine as long as one can identify that. I got that at the first look but I rectified in my actual solution. I wanted to ask one question, what are the cons of using return in join as Tim has used.

Comment: @NitishPatra No cons. It is code pollution. You don't need to use return here at all.